# How to do an ng-repeat that doesn't duplicate the ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs

I need to use ng-repeat to produce several elements but those elements cannot be each wrapped inside a div (this is for box layout purposes where the box layout only works on the immediate children).  For example, I need this result:

```
<div class='box-layout'>
  <div class='item-header>Head 1</div>
  <div class='item-body>Body 1</div>

  <div class='item-header>Head 2</div>
  <div class='item-body>Body 2</div>
</div>
```

There is no wrapping element on the repeated sections. This structure is required to make use of flex-box style layouts. How can I do this with AngularJS?

Comment: Can't you place the ng-repeat on the second level div tag? <div class='box-layout'>
  <div  ng-repeat="item in items" class='item-header>{{item.name}}</div>

Comment: @TorAndersson, each item produces the two div tags, a header and a body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Anders Bornholm said, it can't be done (fyi, [in knockout.js this is easy](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html)).

Albiet its ugly, you *can* accomplish this via a directive, e.g.:

1. [AngularJS ng-repeat with no html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857714/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-no-html-element)
2. [ng-repeat without HTML element (this time really without any)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552708/ng-repeat-without-html-element-this-time-really-without-any)

JS:

```
directive('htmlAppend', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.append(attrs.htmlRepeat);
        }
    };
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class='box-layout'>
  <div class='item-header' ng-repeat="s in sections" html-append="<div class='item-body'>Body</div>">Head</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution! (although I'd like to see it supported by the ng-repeat directive itself in the future :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: can't be done. One of Angular's biggest drawbacks for me personally.

If directive templates would have allowed more than one root element you could have done it with a directive, but that doesn't work either.